# How to find why a Debian package is no longer in the stable release?

Tags: debian

I often run into the situation in which some tutorial (or similar) that I find online recommends installing a Debian package that is no longer available in the latest stable release.  Likewise, sometimes `apt install` lists "suggested packages" that are no longer available<sup>1</sup>.

Is there a formal record of why a Debian package is no longer available?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In fact, at the moment, I am interested in the [`torbrowser-launcher` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=torbrowser-launcher), which `apt` lists among the suggested packages for the [`tor` package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/tor), but my question is not specific to it.  As I wrote above, this is a recurring situation.</sup>

Comment: Probably here is info https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/torbrowser-launcher IIUC it was never in main stable repos, only in backports, testing, unstable ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to check this:

1. Check the open bugs on `torbrowser-launcher` at [bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=0;dist=unstable;ordering=normal;repeatmerged=0;src=torbrowser-launcher).  There are several "Important" bugs. Important bugs are considered release critical, and so if they aren't solved by the next freeze it'll either delay the release of debian bullseye, or it'll more likely be removed.
2. Check `qa.debian.org` for a QA report on the package.  This links you to the [tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/torbrowser-launcher) that Jiri B linked.

If we look at a few events from that page we see:

```
[2019-07-28] Accepted torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-2~bpo10+1 (source amd64) into buster-backports, buster-backports
[2019-07-28] Accepted torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-2~bpo9+2 (source amd64) into stretch-backports-sloppy->backports-policy, stretch-backports-sloppy
[2019-07-28] torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-2 MIGRATED to testing
[2019-04-06] torbrowser-launcher REMOVED from testing
[2018-11-23] torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-2 MIGRATED to testing 
[2018-11-20] Accepted torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-2~bpo9+1 (source) into stretch-backports
[2018-11-17] Accepted torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-2 (source) into unstable
[2018-11-06] Accepted torbrowser-launcher 0.3.1-1~bpo8+1 (source amd64) into jessie-backports-sloppy
```

So we can see that originally, the package was uploaded to `jessie-backports-sloppy`, `stretch-backports` and `unstable`.  Then it migrated from `unstable` to `testing`.  That's all totally normal.

But then you can see on `2019-04-06`, it was REMOVED from `testing`, only to migrate back on `2019-07-28` and be simultaneously updated in all of the `backports` repositories.

In that time-period `testing` was in a freeze period as we anticipated the 10th release of debian `stable`: `buster`.  Things will be removed from `testing` during the freeze period if they should not be included in the `stable` distribution.  If you click on the `REMOVED` note, you can see the official explanation of why it was removed from `testing`:

https://tracker.debian.org/news/1037464/torbrowser-launcher-removed-from-testing/

That explanation refers to a "serious" priority issue raised in the bug-tracker as the official reason why it was removed from `testing`. A "serious" bug during the freeze period will cause a package to be dropped from testing.  In this case, the bug was filed for the sole purpose of preventing the package from being released in debian `stable` and not because of any deficiency in the package.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=926042#5

There is some good explanation in that bug by several people on why the package should not be distributed in `stable` and they describe that you should get it from `backports`.